# ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown charset id 255

Tags: database, tidb

I have deployed TiDB in the production environment. Yesterday I found that some machines failed to connect to the database and it occurred that `ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown charset id 255`. There was no problem with the privilege. What caused this problem and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of the charset of the operating system. Use `echo $LANG` to see the charset. If it is utf8, you can connect to TiDB using `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: If I am using a different version of MySQL client, this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to this issue. Downgrade mysql client to 5.7 works for me.
https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/issues/6942